# How to calculate count on of table column using group by clause in linq

Tags: asp.net, linq

I'm new to linq.
In c# I'm doing as follows to get the count of one column.

```
SELECT   DispatcherName,
         ActivityType,
         CONVERT(BIGINT,COUNT(ActivityType)) AS Total
FROM     ACTIVITYLOG
GROUP BY DispatcherName,
         ActivityType
ORDER BY Total DESC
```

Can any one tell m,how I can achieve the same thing using LINQ.

Update:

HI I did as follows and got the reslut.
But I'm not able to convert result to datatable.
this is how I did.
here dt is datatabe with two columns Dispatchername and ActivityType.

```
 var query1 = from p in dt.AsEnumerable()
                             group p by new
                             {
                                 DispatcherName = p.Field<string>("Dispatchername"),
                                 Activity = p.Field<string>("ActivityType"),
                             }
                                 into pgroup
                                 let count = pgroup.Count()
                                 orderby count
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     Count = count,
                                     DispatcherName = pgroup.Key.DispatcherName,
                                     Activity = pgroup.Key.Activity
                                 };
```

pls help me out asap.

Comment: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your results returned back to a DataTable, one option is to use the [`CopyToDataTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386921.aspx) method.

Here's a live example: http://rextester.com/XHX48973

This method basically requires you to create a dummy table in order to use its `NewRow` method - the only way to create a DataRow, which is required by CopyToDataTable.

```
var result = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(p => new { 
           DispatcherName = p.Field<string>("DispatcherName"),
           Activity = p.Field<string>("ActivityType")})
    .Select(p => {
      var row = dummy.NewRow();
        row["Activity"] = p.Key.Activity;
        row["DispatcherName"] = p.Key.DispatcherName;
        row["Count"] = p.Count();
        return row;
    })
    .CopyToDataTable();
```

Perhaps a better way might be just fill in the rows directly, by converting to a `List<T>` and then using `ForEach`.

```
DataTable dummy = new DataTable();
dummy.Columns.Add("DispatcherName",typeof(string));
dummy.Columns.Add("Activity",typeof(string));
dummy.Columns.Add("Count",typeof(int));

dt.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(p => new { DispatcherName = p.Field<string>("DispatcherName"),
        Activity = p.Field<string>("ActivityType")})
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(p => {
      var row = dummy.NewRow();
        row["Activity"] = p.Key.Activity;
        row["DispatcherName"] = p.Key.DispatcherName;
        row["Count"] = p.Count();
        dummy.Rows.Add(row);
    });
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/TFZNEO48009

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you tell me pls how to sort result by count desc order?

Answer (score 5):

```
from c in ACTIVITYLOG
group c by new {c.DispatcherName, c.ActivityType} into g
orderby g.Count() descending
select new { g.Key.DispatcherName, g.Key.ActivityType, Total = g.Count() }
```

Comment: Masterful. +1 I'm still learning LINQ, and the use of the "new" keyword in this context is awesome. +woot

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
 IList<ACTIVITYLOG> allActivityLogs;
            var result = (from c in allActivityLogs
                          select new
                          {
                              DispatcherName = c.DispatcherName,
                              ActivityType = c.ActivityType,
                              Total = c.ActivityType.Count
                          }).OrderByDescending(x => x.Total)
                         .GroupBy(x => new { x.DispatcherName, x.ActivityType });
```

You only need to substitute the allActivityLogs collection with the actual collection of your entities.

Comment: I dont think this will "do the trick" For starters what makes you think his `ActivityType` property has a `Count`?